# Why javascript block parallel downloading?

Tags: javascript, performance

Can anyone please tell me why javascript block parallel downloading?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what downloading is being blocked?

Comment: In YSlow they mentioned, we have to put the javascript at the bottom because the javascript block parallel downloading..

Comment: javascript blocks all other downloading until it is done. voting to reopen, since it is a great question

Answer (score 4):

If the JavaScript has this code...

```
document.write('Hello from 1998');
```

...it would need to modify the DOM *in place* and do it before it loads anything else.

So the browser waits for the script to download before moving on.

[Further reading](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/non-blocking-async-defer/) thanks to [Joeri Sebrechts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20980/joeri-sebrechts).

Comment: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/non-blocking-async-defer/ contains the explanation and the solution

Comment: +1 for Further reading pointer :)

Answer (score 1):

the browser has to download a list of resources. This list is specified by the markup. Resources can be images, css files, JS files... Resources other than JS files are downloaded in parallel even they came from the same domain.

JS Files are downloaded sequentially to guarantee the order of execution according to the order of occurrence in the dom. Also they block the download of other resources since the js could manipulate the dom.

Modern browsers download JS files in parallel to enhance the download process. But they interpret and execute the JS in the order of there occurrence in the dom, too.

Answer (score -1):

Quote from [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom):

> The problem caused by scripts is that
>   they block parallel downloads. The
>   HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that
>   browsers download no more than two
>   components in parallel per hostname.
>   If you serve your images from multiple
>   hostnames, you can get more than two
>   downloads to occur in parallel. While
>   a script is downloading, however, the
>   browser won't start any other
>   downloads, even on different
>   hostnames.

Comment: Ya.. I know.. My question is why the browser don't start any other download when the script is downloading?